# Abbreviated Journal Titles in Mendeley bibtex?

Tags: latex, bibtex, mendeley

I am trying to get abbreviated journal names into bibtex from Mendeley, but am running into issues. I have followed the instructions [here](http://bits-of-information.org/openminded/abbrev-mendeley/) to activate abbreviations but they do not appear in bibtex. For example, if I **'Copy as formatted citation'** I get:

```
1. Baylor, L. R. et al. Pellet fuelling, ELM pacing and disruption mitigation technology development for ITER. Nucl. Fusion 49, 085013 (2009).
```

Which has the abbreviated journal (Nucl. Fusion). However if I **'Copy as BibTeX entry'** I get:

```
@article{Baylor2009,
author = {Baylor, L. R. and Combs, S. K. and Foust, C. R. and Jernigan, T. C. and Meitner, S. J. and Parks, P. B. and Caughman, J. B. and Fehling, D. T. and Maruyama, S. and Qualls, A. L. and Rasmussen, D. A. and Thomas, C. E.},
journal = {Nuclear Fusion},
pages = {085013},
title = {{Pellet fuelling, ELM pacing and disruption mitigation technology development for ITER}},
volume = {49},
year = {2009}
}
```

Which does not have the abbreviated journal.

Are there any direct solutions to this that don't involve work arounds?

Thanks for your help.

Here's a MWEB:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=nature,maxnames=1,uniquelist=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{key,
   author = {Baylor, L. R. and Combs, S. K. and Foust, C. R. and Jernigan, T. C. and Meitner, S. J. and Parks, P. B. and Caughman, J. B. and Fehling, D. T. and Maruyama, S. and Qualls, A. L. and Rasmussen, D. A. and Thomas, C. E.},
   journal = {Nuclear Fusion},
   pages = {085013},
   title = {{Pellet fuelling, ELM pacing and disruption mitigation technology development for ITER}},
   volume = {49},
   year = {2009}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{key}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)? There are ways to replace the full names with abbreviations from within tex but this depends on how exactly you create your bibliography.

Comment: Sure thing, I added it to the original question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could tell `biblatex` to replace the full name with an abbreviation of your choice:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=nature,maxnames=1,uniquelist=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{key,
   author = {Baylor, L. R. and Combs, S. K. and Foust, C. R. and Jernigan, T. C. and Meitner, S. J. and Parks, P. B. and Caughman, J. B. and Fehling, D. T. and Maruyama, S. and Qualls, A. L. and Rasmussen, D. A. and Thomas, C. E.},
   journal = {Nuclear Fusion},
   pages = {085013},
   title = {{Pellet fuelling, ELM pacing and disruption mitigation technology development for ITER}},
   volume = {49},
   year = {2009}
}
\end{filecontents}


\DeclareSourcemap{
 \maps[datatype=bibtex,overwrite=true]{
  \map{
    \step[fieldsource=journal,
          match=\regexp{Nuclear\sFusion},
          replace={Nucl.\ Fusion}]
  }
 }
}

\begin{document}

\cite{key}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: After some more digging it doesn't look like you can fix this directly from Mendeley, so I think that this `biblatex` workaround is the way to go! Thanks!